# StructureMap register generic types against all possible concrete implementations

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have the following:

```
public interface ICommand { }
public class AddUser : ICommand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommandHandler<T> : IHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Execute(T command);
}

public class AddUserHandler : ICommandHandler<AddUser>
{
    public void Execute(AddUser command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: User added: {1}", GetType().Name, command.Name);
    }
}

public class AuditTrailHandler : ICommandHandler<ICommand>
{
    public void Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Have seen a command of type {1}", GetType().Name, command.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

I would like to use scanning to register the ICommandHandler<> so that I get the following types in the container:

- `ICommandHandler<AddUser>` with concrete type `AddUserHandler`
- `ICommandHandler<AddUser>` with concrete type `AuditTrailHandler`

I have tried this with an implementation of IRegistrationConvention and at one point I had it working but I just cannot get my head around how I did it.

The goal is to be able to execute several handlers for a specific ICommand implementation like so:

```
// A method in CommandDispatcher
public void SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : ICommand {
   var commandHandlers = container.GetAllInstances<ICommandHandler<T>>();
   foreach (var commandHandler in commandHandlers) {
       commandHandler.Execute(command);    
   }
}
```

I want the `AuditTrailHandler<ICommand>` to execute for all concrete implementations of ICommand, hence the need to register them for all types of ICommand.

Secondary objective would be if I could inject a collection of `ICommandHandlers<ICommand>` into my CommandDispatcher instead of the container, but I think that's impossible with the structure I have now. Prove me wrong if you have any ideas.

**EDIT - solved**

I added a non generic interface that my generic interface implements and then I also added an Abstract `CommandHandler<T>` so I don't have to implement the CanHandle or Execute(object) methods in all my handlers.

This is the working structure:

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    void Execute(object command);
    bool CanHandle(ICommand command);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler, IHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Execute(T command);
}

public abstract class AbstractCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    public abstract void Execute(T command);
    public void Execute(object command)
    {
        Execute((T)command);
    }

    public virtual bool CanHandle(ICommand command)
    {
        return command is T;
    }
}
```

And since this originally was a StructureMap question, here is the Scan to add this:

```
Scan(x =>
        {
            x.AssemblyContainingType<MyConcreteHandler>();
            x.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<MyConcreteHandler>();
            x.AddAllTypesOf<ICommandHandler>();
            x.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
```

This makes me able to inject an IEnumerable in my CommandDispatcher and execute like so:

```
public void SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
    {
        var commandHandlersThatCanHandle = commandHandlers.Where(c => c.CanHandle(command));
        foreach (var commandHandler in commandHandlersThatCanHandle)
        {
            commandHandler.Execute(command);    
        }
    }
```

This makes me able to execute CommandHandlers that support AddUser (like the AddUserHandler), but I'm also able to execute a handler that support ICommand (like the AuditTrailHandler).

This is sweet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have all of the command handlers injected into the command dispatcher, create a new, non-generic `ICommandHandler` interface which `ICommandHandler<T>` derives from. It has an Execute method which takes an object. The downside is that each of your command handlers has to implement that method to call the typed overload:

```
public class AddUserHandler : ICommandHandler<AddUser>
{
    public void Execute(object command)
    {
        Execute((AddUser)command);
    }
    public void Execute(AddUser command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: User added: {1}", GetType().Name, command.Name);
    }
}
```

This will enable your command dispatcher to have a constructor dependency on `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler>`, which StructureMap will automatically populate.

In SendCommand you have 2 ways of getting the appropriate set of handlers. A simple filter based on type:

```
commandHandlers.OfType<ICommandHandler<T>>
```

or add a `CanHandle(object command)` to the `ICommandHandler` interface:

```
commandHandlers.Where(x => x.CanHandle(command))
```

The second approach requires more code, but gives you a little more flexibility by allowing you to attach handler by more than just type. This may make solving your first problem easier, by making your `AuditTrailHandler` always return `true` from `CanHandle`.

Comment: That is brilliant!
I did have the CanHandle method before, but removed it since I thought StructureMap magic could do it for me.
I even went a bit further and made an abstract CommandHandler<T> and put that in between the generic interface and concrete class, so that I can benefit from the CanHandle method without having to implement it in all derived classes.
Awesome, Thanks!