# Generic covariant cast or cast to real type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, cqrs

Trying to build a CQRS solution, I have the following code trying to find a Handler and then invoke a Handle() method.

The code below works but it's annoying to use reflection when we know that all IHandleCommand<> have a Handle method, this could be resolved at compiletime, I belive!

Do I have to use `dynamic` in some way?

```
public void SendCommand(Command command)
{
    Type handlerType = typeof(IHandleCommand<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
    object handler = container.Resolve(handlerType);
    handler.GetType().GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, new object[] { command });
}
```

Here's the other types used above

```
public class Command {}

public class MyCommand : Command {}

public interface IHandleCommand<T>
{
void Handle(T command);
}

public class MyCommandHandler : IHandleCommand<MyCommand>
{
    public void Handle(MyCommand command)   {}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by annoying?  The code is written.. it works...

Comment: It bothers me a lot to invoke Handle() by reflection when I think there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I found out some solutions:

```
dynamic handler = container.Resolve(handlerType);
handler.Handle(command as dynamic);
```

But if I send command as dynamic to a generic method I will get Command as it's real type as T to do magic with. Also the call to Handle() can be resolved at compile time. Then there's no need for generic covariant casting, which turns out to be problem from the beginning.

```
public void SendCommand(Command command)
{
    Invoke(command as dynamic);
}

private void Invoke<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
    var handler = container.Resolve<IHandleCommand<T>>();
    handler.Handle(command);
}
```

It is really nice, but I won't go entirely for that solution since I don't registrate command handlers, i'll use this:

```
private void Invoke<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
    Type handlerType = CommandToHandlerType(command);
    var handler = (IHandleCommand<T>)container.Resolve(handlerType);
    handler.Handle(command);
}
```

CommandToHandlerType() just searches an assembly for a type implementing IHandleCommand of T

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar to that where I used a container (StructureMap in my case) to get handler instances from.

Check out that question and its answers: [StructureMap register generic types against all possible concrete implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733424/structuremap-register-generic-types-against-all-possible-concrete-implementation)

Comment: Great link, I'll need to dig in to your solution.

Comment: I suppose I could implement a non-generic interface for the handler with a void Execute(object command) but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I used Autofac to solve the problem.
Here is what I ended up with

Assuming this interface

```
public interface IHandleCommand<T> where T : Command
{
  void Handle(T command);
}
```

The Servicebus will call something like this

```
private readonly IComponentContext container;

public InProcessBus(IComponentContext container)
{
  this.container = container;
}

public void Send<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
  if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Command");
  container.Resolve<IHandleCommand<T>>().Handle(command);
}
```

and my Autofac CommandsHandlersModule

```
public class CommandsHandlersModule : Autofac.Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
     builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CartCommandsHandler).Assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandleCommand<>))
       .SingleInstance();
   }
}
```

Than from your app you call

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new CommandsHandlersModule());
```

Comment: My SendCommand() is a WPF operation and generics is not allowed in wpf, it really helps to have the <T>.