# Can one inject a named instance based on the ctor arg name with a convention?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

With StructureMap, can one inject instances based on their name by convention, like so:

Ctor:

```
public HomeController(IQuery getItemByProductNumberQuery, IQuery getCustomerById)
```

StructureMap config:

```
x.For<IQuery>().Add<GetItemByProductNumberQuery>().Named("getItemByProductNumberQuery");
x.For<IQuery>().Add<GetCustomerById>().Named("getCustomerById");
```

I'm working with legacy code, so changing the DI container is a huge undertaking, but it would be interesting to know about other containers' solution to the problem at hand as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing an abstraction in your code base. Under normal circumstances, a service (`IQuery` in your case) should be unambiguous, which isn't the case in your situation. Identifying them by the argument name is often error prone and leads to a DI configuration that is hard to maintain. This doesn't always have to be this way (as can be seen in [this example](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/02/PrimitiveDependencies.aspx)), but it probably is in your case.

To solve this, make your `IQuery` interface generic:

```
public interface IQuery<TParameters, TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TParameters parameters);
}
```

This allows you to register all implementations of this interface by their closed generic representation, and allow your control to depend on this closed generic representation:

```
public HomeController(
    IQuery<GetItemByProductNumberParameters, Item> getItemQuery, 
    IQuery<GetCustomerByIdParameters, Customer> getCustomerById)
```

As you can see, each query defines a 'XXXParameters' object. This is a DTO that contains all parameters needed to run the query. The code in your `HomeController` might look like this:

```
public View Item(int productNumber)
{
    var parameters = new GetItemByProductNumberParameters
    {
        ProductNumber = productNumber,
        // other parameters here
    };

    Item item = this.getItemQuery.Handle(parameters);

    return this.View(item);
}
```

It might be a bit difficult to batch register all `IQuery<TParameter, TResult>` implementations in one go with StructureMap, but [this SO question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733424/structuremap-register-generic-types-against-all-possible-concrete-implementation). And if not, using another DI container might yield better results.

You can find more information about why you want to model your queries this way in this article: [Meanwhile… on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).